# What is the right bash syntax to add two numbers from string array?

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I have to read a string from pipe, and I am using

```
read -a line
```

for that.

And then I need to calculate two numbers from the string (the string contains numbers at this point exactly at the places I need).

And then I am trying to write this:

```
number= 10*${line[4]} + ${line[5]}
```

and getting these errors from bash:

```
local: `10*1': not a valid identifier
local: `+': not a valid identifier
```

How to write it correctly that those string fields will be converted to numbers ("50" to 50 etc.) and participate in expression?

Comment: bash hack to get number is smth like $((var+0))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see an example:

```
$ a[0]=12
$ a[1]=23
$ res=$(( ${a[0]} + ${a[1]}))
$ echo $res
35
```

So in your case you need to do

```
num=$(( 10*${line[4]} + ${line[5]}))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=(2 3 4)
let sum=${a[0]}+${a[1]}+${a[2]}
echo $sum
```

Comment: In this context, you'll have to be careful to escape multiplication so the `*` does not expand into filenames

Answer (score 1):

Another way to evaluate expressions:

```
result=$(expr "1" + "2")
echo $result #=> 3
```

See the expr man page:

```
man expr
```